# Redirect multiple domains to SSL - NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have the following server config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name default;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    ... and so it continues
```

I also have two domain names, `test.com` and `example.com`. They both point to the IP adress from the server. If I go to `test.com`, it gets redirected to https fine, but if I go to `example.com`, it gets redirected to the https version of `test.com` instead of the https version of `example.com`. Why does this happen? I'm very new to server configs. On other Server Fault answers I only found to use the `$host` variable but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could be the browser cache - clear the cache or use private/incognito mode. Also, analyse the HTTP headers using a suitable plugin.

Comment: That actually did the job. Didn't know the browser was capable of caching server settings! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue and indeed the browser cache was the problem!

Just a note on that: one of the best solution (not cached) to check the redirects would be to `curl` the server from command line:

```
curl -I http://my-server.com
```

About the browser cache, clearing the whole cache - [refreshyourcache.com](http://refreshyourcache.com) - would work but it's slightly overkill!
Another way to ensure the browser is not using the cache is to request a slightly different url, ie:

```
http://my-server.com?randomString
```

Another point I wanted to quote after reading [the server_name nginx doc](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names): it feels that the recommended way to accept multiple domain names is to use the empty server_name `""` rather than `default`, ie for your config example:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "";
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name "";
    root /home/forge/default/public;

    ... and so it continues
```

But please someone, correct me if I'm wrong! :)